# Edit Chart Data in Microsoft Word using Python

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a template in Microsoft word that contains a line chart and I would like to write python code to edit the data. Is there a way I can do this? I've tried looking online but couldn't find any good resources for this. Right now I'm using the `docxtpl` library to fill in some text but I don't think it can handle editing Microsoft chart data.

I know an alternative would be to create a chart using some library, saving it as an image and than adding it to microsoft as an image but I wanted to avoid this. Any help would be great!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472883/17064199).